# Calculating the Big-O from output

Tags: language-agnostic, big-o

5000
10

10000
22

20000
49

40000
108

80000
234

160000
518

Function is not given. Assume that the first entry of the pairs is N, while the second part is an indication of time. How does one go about calculating the Big O? I've been searching around, and most explanations come down to using the function itself...

Comment: That looks pretty straight-forward. As the N grows to double the size, the time grows to double the size. So the complexity is O(n).

Comment: How do you mean exactly? 108->234?

Comment: You don't expect the numbers to be exact, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Least squares fitting method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares). This question is already asked on mathematics.stackexchange so you can refer to the related answer there.

Related answer: [How can I find which function corresponds to a set of data points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475803/how-can-i-find-which-function-corresponds-to-a-set-of-data-points)

If you write an implementation you can use it for any data set to figure out the time complexity of an algorithm.